# Angular 4 Http Chain Requests

Tags: angular, api, http

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the result of an Http request to make another Http request. Let's make it clear with example;
Firstly I getting data from this api:

```
[{"id": 1}]
```

Secondly I should getting data from another api and result is :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum", }]
```

So I should check api İf first data `id =1`then I should post `"id labore ex et quam laborum"`. I'm open with any advice. Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear... as far as I understand, you want to request 2nd one with name: id labore ex et quam laborum"  if 1st http request , response is > id:1, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. İf first api result is 1 then ı should post html "id labore ex et quam laborum"

Comment: try this.http.get(url).subscribe( (data) => if(data.id == 1) this.http.post(url, data))

Comment: but first api results more than one. İ cant do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the rxjs `switchMap` operator.

Just import it:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

And then use it like this:

```
this.http.get('/api/items').switchMap(data => {
  // do something with your data
  return this.http.get(`https://api.com/${data.id}`); // use it for example in your http request
}).subscribe(data => {
    this.results = data['results'];
});
```

You can find more about it [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).